# drupal 7 - can't restore anonymous user

Tags: session, drupal-7, anonymous-users

I noticed than my anonymous user was removed by something when i noticed $_SESSION was crashed for anonymous user

After gogling like a panther i take a look in my users sqltable and effectively the uid = 0 was not here.

So i apply the solve given by many guys like [him](https://drupal.org/node/1029506) : add this in sql:

```
insert into users (name, pass, mail, theme, signature, language, init, timezone) values ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
update users set uid = 0 where name = '';
INSERT INTO users_roles VALUES(0,1);
```

and then flush cache. However even if the row uid = 0 is now with us, the anonymous is still not showed on the user list and the $_SESSION is still crashed.

Does anyone can help me to fix this issue?
(apologies for my english)

EDIT:
as thought I can't figure out to fix this, i give you a nice shot of my row:

[image]

Pls need help, i can't replace $_SESSION usage

Answer (score 0):

Ok that's weird but it seems that the session is not started for the anonymous user, so adding this code in my module solve my problem:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    // session isn't started
    session_start();
}
```

But if someone know a proper way to fix this, i take it